# Why does my hamburger dropdown menu with Bootstrap 4 not work correctly?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I feel like this shouldn't be as complex as it's been for me. I've been searching for days on how to get this bootstrap simple hamburger dropdown to work. I've rearranged the hierarchy of how the files load in the head. I've updated all of my min.js and min.cs versions, I even started a whole new project to see if this issue was with my last one specifically. Anything helps!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- For Angular Routing -->
  <base href='/'>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
<!--Navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-light light-blue lighten-4">

  <!-- Navbar brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <!-- Collapse button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler toggler-example" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent1"
    aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><span class="dark-blue-text"><i
        class="fas fa-bars fa-1x"></i></span></button>

  <!-- Collapsible content -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent1">

    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Links -->

  </div>
  <!-- Collapsible content -->

</nav>
<!--/.Navbar-->
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Try removing the jquery slim and use the full on jquery.

Comment: Hello! If you are new to how Angular fundamentally works I advice you should go for the [Hero tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial). For starter you haven't included the bootstrapping component in your file(assuming this is the index.html file).

Comment: @JohnDavid where exactly could I find the full version? Is it not from the jQuery / Bootstrap sites?

Comment: @Saylor23 just remove the word 'slim' from the URL. Make it https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js instead.

Comment: @Lucho Thank you for the link. This is my "projects" page component, not the index.html inside my dist folder. This is the content from index.html.

Comment: @Lucho Oops looks like I cant reply with code. Sorry, I am new here :p

Comment: @Lucho How would I include the bootstrap component into the file? Pointing it to the bootstrap folder in my node_modules?

Comment: @JohnDavid Hmm that doesn't seem to have worked.

Comment: @Saylor23 it would be nice if you could give some more examples of what's going on here. I know in the past I've used bootstrap4 and had menu issue. The slim version of jQuery doesn't have any of the animation or ajax in it.

Comment: @JohnDavid Inside of my projects-page component in the projectspage.html is where I am having this issue. The code is directly from the bootstrap website for the hamburger menu dropdown. I've pasted the jquery, ajax, and bootstrap.js which also came from the bootstrap site. The page only loads the text "NavBar" on the left side of the page, and the dropdown box is empty and won't dropdown at all. I hope this is enough context.

Comment: @Saylor23 it's still hard to debug angular without seeing all of the code. Are you sure that your files are all being loaded onto the page?

Comment: @JohnDavid would linking a git repository be helpful? https://github.com/jonathanmsaylor/portfolio

Comment: @Saylor23 Yes please. Or a fiddle.. Whatever would be useful.